# sort property list according to inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, early-binding

I have certain classes that all inherit from other classes. Each class, only inherits from one other class, never two classes.
I've also got a Base-Class that is the "top" of my inheritance tree.
Classes are for example:

```
public class IfcAlignment : IfcLinearPositioningElement
{
    public IfcAlignmentTypeEnum PredefinedType {get; set;}
}
public class IfcLinearPositioningElement : IfcProduct
{
   public IfcCurve Axis {get; set;}
}
public class IfcProduct : IfcObject
{
   public IfcObjectPlacement ObjectPlacement {get; set;}
   public IfcProductRepresentation Representation {get; set;}
}
public class IfcObject: IfcRoot
{
   IfcLabel ObjectType {get; set;}
}
public class IfcRoot : IfcBase
{
   public IfcGloballyUniqueId GlobalId {get; set;}
   public IfcOwnerHistory OwnerHistory {get; set;}
   public IfcLabel Name {get; set;}
   public IfcText Description {get; set;}
}
public abstract class IfcBase
{
   public int _ID {get; set;}
}
```

This is one set of inheritance within my structure. When I now call the properties of IfcAlignment and loop through them, I get them in this order:

1. PredefinedType
2. Axis
3. ObjectPlacement
4. Representation
5. ObjectType
6. GlobalId
7. OwnerHistory
8. Name
9. Description
10. _ID

However I need these properties in the order "top-to-bottom" so:

1. _ID
2. GlobalId
3. OwnerHistory
4. Name
5. Description
6. ObjectType
7. ObjectPlacement
8. Representation
9. Axis
10. PredefinedType

Therfore I wanted to implement a method in every class, that you can call and that would sort the properties in the correct order. the method looks like this so far:

```
        override public List<PropertyInfo> SortMyProperties(object entity)
        {
            List<PropertyInfo> returnValue = new List<PropertyInfo>();
            if (entity is IfcBase && !entity.GetType().Name.Contains("IfcBase"))
            {
                //Here I need to get the actual parent object:
                // I tried the following, which did no work unfortunately:
                // var parent = entity.GetType().BaseType;

                PropertyInfo propInfo = parent.SortMyProperties(parent);

                //get my own properties:
                Type type = entity.GetType();
                var genuineProps = typeof(/*type of the current class*/).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
                foreach (var prop in genuineProps)
                {
                    returnValue.Add(prop);
                }
                return returnValue;
            }
            else
            {
                var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (var prop in properties)
                {
                    returnValue.Add(prop);
                }
                return returnValue;
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to access the parent oject and not just the parent type, which I'm doing in my current code? Are any other suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: Why does it matter what order the properties come in? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: The object I am creating so in my case the IfcAlignment-Object needs to be mapped onto a string following a norm (ISO 10303-21). And the ISO states that the properties need to be listed top to bottom. A resulting string would look like this: #_ID = IFCALIGNMENT(GlobalId, OwnerHistory, Name,...).

Comment: how about linq orderby: `foreach (var prop in genuineProps.OrderBy(g=>g.Name))`

Comment: This part (genuineProps) does work like it should. Because it gets the properties declared in the current object and just adds them to my returnValue-List. So I don't need to rearrange the properties of that foreach loop. Or did I read your answer wrong?

Comment: i'm just take an example, if something is not in order then sort it. where and how to sort depends on your decisions. what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this. This will be the better solution to achieve your requirement

```
            var type = typeof(IfcAlignment);
            List<string> PropertyNames= new List<string>();
            while(type!=null)
            {
                  var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.DeclaringType == type).Select(x=>x.Name).Reverse().ToList();
                  foreach(string name in properties)
                  {
                       PropertyNames.Add(name);
                  }
                type = type.BaseType;

            }
            PropertyNames.Reverse();
```

Comment: That just worked when I quickly tried it! Thank you so much! Just one last problem: I'm implementing this into another method now. Can I instead of saying typeof(IfcAlignment) also solve that with something like typeof(this.GetType()) so I don't have to rewrite this code for every entity?

Comment: @FlixFix Yes. You can  use typeof(this.GetType()) or if you using from another class, just get the object typeof(obj.GetType())